# can i kill or finish() an Activity in a Thread other than UI thread..?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I was wondering if its possible to create a Thread and kill/finish The Activity, is it Even possible, if yes then how come it does not work in `AsyncTask's doInBackGround()`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should only call finish() from the UI thread.

Comment: ..thanks Romain, is that android Os's specific Beauvoir..? or is there any reason like one Thread cannot interfere with the process of other Thread..?

Comment: Any links to documentation on this?