# Can an Android Activity be resumed after finish()?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

Checking some legacy code I've found this snippet:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    if (!isFinishing()) {
        ...
    }
    super.onResume();
}
```

despite the `super.onResume()` call at the end of the method, which is discouraged:

> Note: Your implementation of these lifecycle methods must always call
>   the superclass implementation before doing any work, as shown in the
>   examples above
>   http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html

I'm concerned about the `if (!isFinishing())` call, does this have sense? as I can see checking Activity code `mFinished` variable is set to true only on `finish()` and `finishActivity()`, can, through the Android Lifecycle, to be resumed an activity which is being destroyed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is interesting. Where did you found that code?

Comment: Is the main activity of my company aplication.

Comment: onDestroy(): The final call you receive before your activity is destroyed. This can happen either because the activity is finishing (someone called finish() on it, or because the system is temporarily destroying this instance of the activity to save space. You can distinguish between these two scenarios with the isFinishing() method. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: @shkschneider I've seen that, but does this have sense in onResume()? I'm assuming that finish() or the system internal call is being executed on UI thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036151/can-i-kill-or-finish-an-activity-in-a-thread-other-than-ui-thread) so, will the activity be resumed while is being destroyed?

Comment: I agree that this code in `onResume()` and even before `super.onResume()` makes no sense to me whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, the legacy code was calling `finish()` under some circunstances at the `onCreate()` method. But taking a look at `onCreate()` [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)):

> You can call finish() from within this function, in which case
>   onDestroy() will be immediately called without any of the rest of the
>   activity lifecycle (onStart(), onResume(), onPause(), etc) executing.

So, this `isFinishing()` call is useless inside `onResume()`

Answer (score 1):

The answer to you question is "no" activity cannot be resumed if it was destroyed.
Here is good discussion:
[Understanding of isFinishing()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227071/understanding-of-isfinishing)

> The reason for this code may be to distinguish between orientation
>   change and actual finishing of the activity     Important to note here
>   is isFinishing: true which means that call to `isFinishing()` in the
>   onDestroy() returns true, i.e. which happens when:
>
> User hits "back" button OR activity's code calls it's `finish()`
>   (`isFinishing()` returns false when activity is geting closed after
>   phone rotaion in order to be started again)

http://ogrelab.ikratko.com/activity-lifecycle-explained-in-details/

Comment: I understand your point, and the reason to use isFinishing() in the onDestroy, but still makes no sense for me in onResume()

Comment: There is no reason to use isFinishing() in the onDestroy because onDestroy may not be called at all.

Comment: That's not what we are discussing here